# Problem with possibly infinite possible solutions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, equilibrium

Problem figure:

[image: 1]

In the problem, the string is light, inextensible and initially, before the application of the external forces, the string is just taut with no tension and the blocks were at rest. The blocks are perfectly rigid and any rotational effect of forces is to be neglected. We are asked to find the tension in the string and the friction acting on the blocks

Here's my attempt to the problem: I first chose the +ve and -ve directions, which I've mentioned in the problem diagram. Now the system, if it will move, will move together as long as the string remains taut (which it will given the arrangement of forces). So the acceleration of the centre of mass of the system will be the same as the acceleration of the blocks themselves.

Now the maximum static friction force that can act on the 2kg block is 6N and that on the 3kg block is 12N. Also the NET  External force on the system is +5N which is less than what the maximum force static friction can apply on the system(which is 18N), and hence static friction will balance this net force, and so the acceleration of the centre of mass of the system and thus that of the blocks will be zero.

Now individually the blocks cannot be supported by static friction as the net force on each blocks is more than what the friction on them can handle. So tension must come into play for the system to remain in equilibrium.

So finally, using all of the above conclusions, I wrote the following Newtonian equations for the equilibrium state of the given system:

My Attempt Diagram:

[image: 2]

$$T - 10 + f_1 = 0$$
$$15 - f_2 - T = 0$$
$$-6 \le f_1 \le 6 $$
$$-12 \le f_2 \le 12$$

We have three variables, but only two equations to solve them along with some inequalities. This system of equations have a lot (possibly infinite) of solutions

Am I missing any other equation, or does this problem actually have a lot of solutions? I actually disagree with the latter as if we physically replicate the scenario we are bound to get some definite values of the variables.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please properly typeset your equations using MathJax (see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/550071 for an introduction).

Comment: The two figures you've posted are the same, but please don't post links to figures.  Embed the figures in the post, and edit the post to include your equations, properly typeset using MathJax.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: thank you for the advice, is the question more readable now?

Comment: I added the Mathjax for you

Comment: That's very kind of you sir, Thank you! Im new to this mathjax stuff but would soon get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious problems with your analysis.

This problem appears to be [statically indeterminate.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statically_indeterminate)  If so, the "real" value of the tension would be determined by knowing the material properties of the string and the blocks (in particular, their elasticity, dimensions, and positions of the attachment points) — information that is not typically provided in introductory free-body problems.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, I would need to consider the material properties of the system in case it is statically indeterminate. Got it!

Comment: I have the feeling that the true solution is the one that minimizes the tension. But I am having a problem justifying my feeling. It is based on the idea that reaction forces are no bigger than necessary to prevent motion. E.G. A weight rests on a table because the table pushes back just hard enough to hold it still.

Comment: I am thinking of it in the following way: If tension does arrive in the string, the string must have extended a little bit(however small of an extension that is). So, atleast one of the blocks(or both) have to move in order to extend the string, so atleast one of them must have limiting static friction acting on them. Verifying by trial and error, if the 2 kg block has limiting friction on it, we have got a solution, but not when the 3 kg block has limiting friction on it

Comment: @mmesser314 I tend to agree, but tricky to justify. I'm imagining another scenario where the first block is clamped down to the table, vastly increasing the normal force and maximum frictional force. In this case, I wouldn't expect there to by any tension at all, since the first block can resist the force on its own  - although it's really the same indeterminate case, it's hard to see how the pulling force gets transmitted through the clamped block. Agree it comes down to the physical subtlety of how exactly a string goes from taut with T=0 to taut with T not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this through a series of similar but simpler problems.

---

(1) The left hand force is $10$ N. The right hand force is $15$ N, which is $5$ N bigger.

$F_L$ <-- | _ | -- $T$ -- | _ | --> $F_L + 5$

If you make $F_L$ bigger, $T$ will increase. But the blocks will not move so long as the right hand force is $5$ N bigger.

Make $F_L = 0$. There is a force of $5$ N on the right hand block.

You will still find many possible solutions that satisfy the equations.

---

(2) Now make the $5$ N force variable. Reduce it to $0$.

You will still find many solutions that leave the blocks motionless.

The obvious solution is the one where blocks sit motionless because they have no forces on them. $T = f_1 = f_2 = 0$.

However, you could add a small spring to the string so there is a small tension. Friction will prevent the two blocks from sliding toward each other. This too is a solution to the original problem.

You can easily figure out how big tension can be before either block starts sliding.

---

You can do the same calculation for problem (1), where the difference is $5$ N.

You can do the same calculation for the original problem where $F_L = 10$ N.

So Michael Seifert was right. The problem is statically indeterminate. There are many possible solutions to this problem.